# How to convert a "landscape" PDF with "pdftocairo -eps" to a correct EPS?

Tags: pdf, eps, poppler

I can't figure out how to convert a "landscape" PDF file with a single picture on it (eg. paperwidth=842 and paperheight=595 points with an image that fills the whole page) with the tool `pdftocairo` to an EPS file.

The output I get is either a shrinked version of the original file (width is scaled from 842 to 595 to fit the "incorrect" pagewidth 595 of the EPS file), or an EPS where the content between 595 and 842 is just cut off (with the `-noshrink` parameter).

Any ideas?

Edit1: `pdftocairo version 0.43.0`

Input PDF:
`pdfinfo  test.pdf 
Creator:        DocType PDF-Emitter (DocType PDF-Emitter v1.9.37-9-g1b2b6f3)
Producer:       Haru Free PDF Library 2.3.0RC2
CreationDate:   Mon Jun  4 11:18:30 2018
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.44 x 841.68 pts
Page rot:       90
File size:      149246 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3`

[Landscape PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkbfq.png)

Converted with pdftocairo -eps test.pdf

[Landscape EPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s3vh.png)

Comment: Can you add a (link to a) sample PDF, please? Which version of Poppler/`pdftocairo` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of Poppler (on my system, it's v0.42.0) has the following command line options which may be of help:

```
$ pdftocairo -h
   pdftocairo version 0.42.0
   Copyright 2005-2016 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
   Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC

Usage: pdftocairo [options] <PDF-file> [<output-file>]
   [....]
  -eps              : generate Encapsulated PostScript (EPS)
   [....]
  -r <fp>           : resolution, in PPI (default is 150)
  -rx <fp>          : X resolution, in PPI (default is 150)
  -ry <fp>          : Y resolution, in PPI (default is 150)
  -scale-to <int>   : scales each page to fit within scale-to*scale-to pixel box
  -scale-to-x <int> : scales each page horizontally to fit in scale-to-x pixels
  -scale-to-y <int> : scales each page vertically to fit in scale-to-y pixels
  -x <int>          : x-coordinate of the crop area top left corner
  -y <int>          : y-coordinate of the crop area top left corner
  -W <int>          : width of crop area in pixels (default is 0)
  -H <int>          : height of crop area in pixels (default is 0)
  -sz <int>         : size of crop square in pixels (sets W and H)
  -cropbox          : use the crop box rather than media box
   [....]
  -level2           : generate Level 2 PostScript (PS, EPS)
  -level3           : generate Level 3 PostScript (PS, EPS)
  -origpagesizes    : conserve original page sizes (PS, PDF, SVG)
  -paper <string>   : paper size (letter, legal, A4, A3, match)
  -paperw <int>     : paper width, in points
  -paperh <int>     : paper height, in points
  -nocrop           : don't crop pages to CropBox
  -expand           : expand pages smaller than the paper size
  -noshrink         : don't shrink pages larger than the paper size
  -nocenter         : don't center pages smaller than the paper size
   [....]
```